# Returning organised list from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

So im currently trying to analyse a list of tuples, and return a list where the unique values in the tuples are ordered as a path (W leads to X, X to Y and so on). i.e

```
[("Y", "Z"), ("W", "X"), ("X", "Y")]
```

as input would return

```
["W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
```

I can use `set(j for i in list for j in i)` to get unique elements, but im struggling to order based on path.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the list forms a single, straight path? What should the output be if you added, say, `("A", "B")` to the list? Or `("X", "A")` or `("A", "Z")`?

Comment: @chepner list given should always have a clean path

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA That ignores the tuple structure and sorts the strings lexicographically. The list `[("Z", "Y"), ("X", "W"), ("Y", "X")]` should produce the list `["Z", "Y", "X", "W"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
edges: Dict[str, str] = {}  # Map source to destination
reverse_edges: Dict[str, str] = {}

for (source, dest) in input_edges:
  edges[source] = dest
  reverse_edges[dest] = source
```

To get the path in order...

```py
path = []

# Pick a node to start from
start = input_edges[0][0]

# Go from the start back to the top of the path
current_node = reverse_edges[start]
while current_node:
  path.insert(0, current_node)
  current_node = reverse_edges.get(current_node)

# Go from the start to the end of the path
current_node = start
while current_node:
  path.append(current_node)
  current_node = edges.get(current_node)

print(path)  # ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

This doesn't handle the various edge cases one could imagine, but it should be enough to get you started!
Things to watch out for...

1. More than one 'root' node `[("A", "C"), ("B", "C")]`
2. A node has more than one destination `[("A", "B"), ("A", "C")]`

Comment: I have tested your code but it seemed `top_most_source` was not `"W"` when input_edges was `[("Y", "Z"), ("W", "X"), ("X", "Y")]`.

Answer (score 1):

it's maybe not the most pythonic way to proceed but you can do like:

```
tuple_list=[("Y", "Z"), ("W", "X"), ("X", "Y"),('B','W'),('A','B')]
result_list=[]

for x,y in sorted(tuple_list):
    if x in result_list:
        ind_x=result_list.index(x)
        result_list.insert(ind_x+1,y)
    elif y in result_list:
        ind_y=result_list.index(y)
        result_list.insert(ind_y,x)
    else:
        result_list.extend([x,y])
```

result:

```
['A', 'B', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```